# Python ImportError: No module named fast

Tags: python-2.7

I try to run python script with `from fast import FAST` and I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named fast
```

I don't know what is this module for and where to get it. Does somebody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of unknown modules, [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/) homepage is main source of information. Looks like you're missing [package for software testing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FAST/2.5) 
Assuming you have pip installer (maybe [How to install pip on windows will be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows), if you're on windows) all you have to do is:

`pip install fast`

which downloads package with it's dependencies and installs it into your local python package library.